# Why does the probability function of a Bernoulli variable $X\sim Bern(p)$ have the form $f(x|p)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, regression, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Why does the probability function of a Bernoulli variable $X\sim Bern(p)$ have the form $f(x|p)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$?

As I understand, the density function $f(x|p)$ for $X\sim Bern(p)$ should satisfy
$$f(0|p)=1-p,\ f(1|p)=p$$
Such functions are certainly not unique. In general, I would also require that $f(x|p)=0$ for $x\neq0,1$. So I would define it as $f(x|p)=(1-p)I_{\{0\}}(x)+pI_{\{1\}}(x)$. But if we only require that the conditions hold at $0$ and $1$, $f(x|p)=(2p-1)x+1-p$ is also a choice.

Why is there only $f(x|p)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ that is used, **especially when maximum likelihood estimation problems are involved**? Is there a theory behind this? Can it be generalized to other discrete distributions?

Comment: The $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ comes from thinking single Bernoulli trial is the same as binomial with size 1.  So the obvious generalisation to binomial distribution can be done with minimal effort (multiplying them is easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a sample $X_1,\cdots ,X_n$, in which there are $a=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ successes and $n-a$ failures. We want to estimate the probability of success. Given a probability $p$, the probability of getting $a$ successes and $n-a$ failures (in the particular order of the given sample) is $$p^a(1-p)^{n-a}$$
The logic behind maximum likelihood estimation requires you to maximize the likelihood function (which is the probability of getting the given sample given the value of $p$ in this case) by varying the value of $p$. If the pmf of a Bernoulli r.v. is chosen to be $f(x|p)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$, then we can come up with the likelihood function $$L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^np^{x_i}(1-p)^{1-x_i}=p^a(1-p)^{n-a}$$
which is our desired probability. Other choices of the p.m.f. like $f(x|p)=(2p−1)x+1−p  $ would give $$L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n((2p−1)x_i+1−p)$$ which would not give a convenient result.